# Bentonite AND Sparkolloid

Tags: techniques, mead

I know from previous questions that you can use both Bentonite followed by Sparkolloid in the same mead. Am I correct in thinking the best process would be add bentonite, give a week, RACK OFF THE SEDIMENT,then add Sparkolloid and give enough time to clear and then a final racking?  The key component I am asking is the racking between the two. I wanted to make sure that was correct thing to do. Thanks all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use bentonite and Sparkaloid at the same time?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/24311/can-you-use-bentonite-and-sparkaloid-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

Racking after clarification is always recommended since adding a clarifying agent often requires mixing it, which would disturb the sediments.

The only time I would not rack when adding a second clarifying agent would be if they work together, like Chitosan and Kieselsol.